# How to do a Computed Column in a View with JOIN relation?

Tags: sql, view, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to create a *Computed Column* in **MyView**.
I have some problems about to create a query with JOIN.

My code looks like this:

```
SysDictTable roleDictTableUserInfo, roleDictTableUserInfo;
DictView dv = new DictView(tableNum(MyView));
idFieldName = dv.computedColumnString(
    'ViewDataSource_1',
    fieldStr(MyView, DataArea),
    FieldNameGenerationMode::WhereClause);

roleDictTableUserInfo    = new SysDictTable(tableNum(UserInfo));
roleDictTableSysUserInfo = new SysDictTable(tableNum(SysUserInfo));

return strFmt('select count (*) from %1 JOIN UserInfo ON SysUserInfo.Id = UserInfo.ID where %2 = %3',
roleDictTable_UserInfo.name(DbBackend::Sql),
roleDictTable_SysUserInfo.fieldName(fieldNum(SysUserInfo, SEC001_UserCompanies), DbBackend::Sql),
idFieldName);
```

In Compile/Sync I have a error

> Error Description SQL: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near '4'.

If I delete the *JOIN* code , I haven't the error.

How I can insert in Computed Column in a View with JOIN relation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 4th parameter is varchar? If so try to put it in quotes (where %3 = '%4').

Comment: so, I done a typing error. I haven't 4th parameter. , MY error is in JOIN beacouse if I delete the JOIN part I haven't error.

Comment: What value is the %1 replaced with?

Comment: Did you test the SQL statement directly in e.g. SQL Management Studio? This should give you a better idea what the syntax error is. Could you also include the final SQL Statement (all placeholders have been replaced with their actual values) in your question?

Comment: It looks like you are joining SysUserInfo with Userinfo table and SysUserInfo table name is passed as parameter one right? Try this then => return strFmt("select count (*) from %1 JOIN UserInfo ON %1.Id = UserInfo.ID where %1.%2 = '%3'",
roleDictTableSysUserInfo.name(DbBackend::Sql),
roleDictTableSysUserInfo.fieldName(fieldNum(SysUserInfo, SEC001_UserCompanies), DbBackend::Sql),
idFieldName);    Verify what is the value coming in idFieldName debugging.